# Using more than once property in Dijkstra algorithm in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dijkstra

Is there any way in Cypher I can use the Dijkstra algorithm to calculate minimal weight with more than one property instead of:

```
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'RELATED_TO>', '1_property') 
yield path, weight
```

to do something like:

```
  CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'RELATED_TO>', '1_property+2_property') 
yield path, weight
```

It doesn't work for me. Do you have suggestions? Cause I want to put into the calculation of the weight the length of the path as an influence on the min weights calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [Memgraph](https://memgraph.com), high-performance, in-memory and transactional graph database. [openCypher](http://www.opencypher.org) and [Bolt](https://boltprotocol.org) compatible. (DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO). Memgraph has built in weighted shortest path feature where the total weight is calculated via user-defined lambda function. Based on this dataset

```
CREATE (n1 {id: 1}) CREATE (n2 {id: 2}) CREATE (n3 {id: 3}) CREATE (n4 {id: 4})
CREATE (n1)-[:E {weight1: 1, weight2: 1}]->(n2)
CREATE (n1)-[:E {weight1: 2, weight2: 10}]->(n3)
CREATE (n2)-[:E {weight1: 3, weight2: 100}]->(n4)
CREATE (n3)-[:E {weight1: 4, weight2: 1}]->(n4);
```

the relevant Memgraph's query is

```
MATCH (a {id: 1})-[
          edges *wShortest (e, n | e.weight1 + e.weight2) total_weight
      ]-(b {id: 4})
RETURN startNode(head(edges)).id +
       reduce(acc = "", edge IN edges | acc + " -> " + endNode(edge).id) AS hops,
       total_weight;
```

with the following result.

```
| hops      | total_weight |
|-----------|--------------|
|1 -> 3 -> 4| 17.0         |
```

Answer (score 0):

For the apoc one you'd need to use an additional property that holds the sum.

For the one in graph algorithms you could use a graph projection that adds the two weights up.

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_single_source_shortest_path

you can use a `nodeQuery` and `relationshipQuery` in the config section.

```
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'weight',
{nodeQuery:'match (n) return id(n) as id', 
 relationshipQuery:'match (n)-[r]->(m) return id(n) as source, id(m) as target, r.weight1+r.weight2 as weight', 
defaultValue:1.0,direction:'OUTGOING'}) 
YIELD nodeId, cost
```